# Connect two socket.io clients together (Establish a socket to socket, cross browser connection)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'd like to know if there's any way to establish a P2P connection between two browsers using socket.io-client (but I'm willing to use anything else that may do the trick).

Both browsers are currently connected to a node.js app serving HTTP requests with Express, which stores both clients's IP addresses (and ports when running locally). What I'd like to do is add a third connection that links both clients (let's call them A and B) directly, so that messages/data will go straight from one client to another, without transiting through the node.js server.

Is that feasible? If so, how?

So far, I've tried connecting the two clients (let's call them A and B) with the following code:

Client A:

```
A_to_server_socket = io();

A_to_server_socket.on('p2p', function(address_B){

    A_to_B_socket = io(address_B); // Instantiates a new socket

    A_to_B_socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Connected!');
    });  
});
```

I'm not sure about the code for client B. However I've tried:

1. repeat the above code for B, using B's own address (to override the default of connecting to the server)
2. repeat the above code for B, this time using A's address
3. having B_to_server_socket listen for a new connect event

However regardless of B's code, when running A's code I'm confronted with a "Cross-Origin Request blocked" error on Firefox, or  "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" followed by "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" on Chrome.

Any hints towards a solution, or insights for better understanding the problem and how sockets work would be most welcome.

Comment: The client-side socket.io library doesn't listen for incoming connections and, if it did, incoming connections would be blocked by whatever firewall the browser is behind.  The whole principle of WebSockets is that the client connects outbound to the server and that's how you deal with the firewall.  The server (or another client) can't connect to the a client.

Comment: Oh, and I should add that browsers don't allow for listening to incoming connections so this isn't just a socket.io limitation.

Comment: OK. But let's say I don't have a firewall, like when I'm running the app locally. There's really no way to "force" a connection between two client sockets by telling them to listen to one another's IP+PORT?

Comment: No, there is not because the browser will not listen for a new connection.  It simply doesn't do that for webSockets (for security reasons).  It only makes outbound connections.  One side has to listen for new a connection in order to directly connect two endpoints, so if no browser is ever listening, then you can't make a direct webSocket connection between two browsers - that's just how TCP works.  You can connect each browser to an intermediary server and exchange data through the server.

Comment: Also, there wouldn't be any way around this limitation, as in having client A connect to the server, who then passes it (= socket parameters)  down to B, or overwriting a client's packets's 'origin' field with the  server's IP's address? I don't mind getting my hands dirty if I can make it work :)

Comment: You're in a browser (with it's associated security limitations).  You just don't have any tools available to make a direct P2P connection and TCP is designed to prevent the kind of remaking of an existing TCP connection by an outside agent that you're proposing.  Packets could be rewritten by an outside agent to force them to go somewhere differently, but then they're going through one of your servers anyway (to get rewritten) so why bother.

Comment: OK thanks. I guess that makes a lof of sense security-wise. Looks like my solution is webRTC then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to summarize my comments into an answer.

In TCP, a connection is made when one endpoint A connects to another endpoint B.  To connect to endpoint B, that host must be "listening" for incoming connections originating from other hosts.  In a typical web request, the browser establishes a TCP connection to the web server and this works because the web server is listening for incoming requests on a specific port and when one of those requests comes in, it accepts the incoming request to establish an active TCP connection.  So, you must have one side initiating the request and another side listening for the request.

For various security reasons, browsers themselves don't "listen" for incoming connections so you can't connect directly to them.  They only allow you to connect outbound to some other listening agent on the internet.  So, if a browser never listens for an incoming webSocket connection, then you can't establish a true peer-to-peer (e.g. browser-to-browser) webSocket connection.

Furthermore, TCP is designed so that you can't have two browsers both connect to a common server and then somehow have that server connect up their pipelines such that the two browser are now just wired directly to each other.  TCP just doesn't work that way.  It is possible to have an agent in the middle forwarding packets from one client to another via a separate connection to each (that's how Chat applications generally work), but the agent in the middle can't simply plug the two TCP connections together such that the packets go directly from one client to the other (and no longer go through the server) as a fireman would connect two firehoses.  TCP just doens't work that way.  It might be possible to have some complicated scheme that involved rewriting packet headers to a packet sent from endPoint A was forwarded to endPoint B and looked like it came from the server instead, but that still involves the server as the middleman or proxy.

The usual way to solve this problem is to just let each browser connect to a common server and have the server act as the middleman or traffic cop, forwarding packets from one browser to another.

Existing P2P applications (outside of browsers) work by having each client actually listen for incoming connections (act like a server) so that another client can connect directly to them.  P2P itself is more complicated than this because one needs to have a means of discovering an IP address to connect to (since clients typically aren't in DNS) and often there are firewalls in the way that need some cooperation between the two ends in order to make the firewall allow the incoming connection.  But, alas, this capability of listening for an incoming connection is not something a browser from plain javascript will allow you to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no something like "connection between two browsers using socket.io-client."

But there is "Both browsers are connected to a node.js app serving HTTP requests with Express, which keeps track of both clients's IP addresses (and ports when running locally)."

If you want to have P2P connection between two browser, following may be a way to do so.

1. when you get client A connection, join to a room "P2P"
2. when you get client B connection, join to a room "P2P"
3. to exchange between client A and client B, use

   socket.broadcast.to('P2P').emit("message", "Good Morning");

Hope this may help.

Comment: So that's what I aalready have set up. Now what I'm trying to achieve is a real P2P connection between two browsers, so that data sent over this connection will not transit through the browser anymore. If that's possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-p2p

> This module provides an easy and reliable way to setup a WebRTC
> connection between peers and communicate using events (the
> socket.io-protocol).
>
> Socket.IO is used to transport signaling data and as a fallback for
> clients where WebRTC PeerConnection is not supported.

In short, this would allow you to use the WebRTC p2p library to coordinate connecting clients p2p at the server, and from there, proceed with what is essentially a peer to peer websocket/socket.io-client connection.

This would allow p2p audio/video/text/binary over what is basically socket.io.

Just to throw it out there, google chrome and other browsers will block audio/video if it is not over HTTPS (except for localhost url) as a security precaution. This is a little off topic, but if you run into this problem during development or testing, I would consider setting-up a VPS (digital ocean droplet runs like $6/mo). Setup an Nginx reverse proxy: We will connect your dev machine port 3000 to the servers port 3000 using SSH. So configure Nginx to grab port 3000 and kick it out it over HTTPS on port 443. Now use Let's Encrypt to grab a free TLS Certificate and install it for Nginx. From there, finally, use SSH to forward your development machine's HTTP port 3000 to the servers port 3000. Make sure any firewall you have on the server is open for port 443. Now you, and others, can do local development, accessing it through a legitimate domain name over HTTPS.

Good luck!